# NSMutableArray addObject not working uitableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am a beginning iPhone developer.

I have a `UITableView` but I am having trouble making it work with an `NSMutableArray`.

I have allocated and initialized my array: `dataArray` I have also connected my tableview's `dataSource` and `delegate`.

This is my code:

*SecondViewControllerModal.m*

```
@implementation SecondViewControllerModal

-(IBAction)addArray:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:subjectName.text, setLetter.text, setOrder.text , nil];
    SecondViewController *c=[[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [c addToArray:content];
}

...
```

(`addArray` is called when the user presses a button)

*SecondViewController.m*

```
-(void)addToArray:(NSArray *)content {

    NSString *setSubject = [content objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *setLetter = [content objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *setOrder = [content objectAtIndex:2];

    [dataArray addObject:setSubject];

    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [dataArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self->tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

**NOTE**: I am using storyboards and a tabbed view application and I only need to run this on an iPad if that makes any difference.

If I haven't included enough detail or you have any questions about the code please leave a comment.

**EDIT**: This is how my popover looks like in xcode:

[image]

Comment: Did you check with NSLog statements? Is content valid? Is dataArray? setSubject?

Comment: Where are you actually presenting the second view controllers view on screen ? If you're using storyboard you probably shouldn't just alloc/init the second view controller but you should trigger a segue...

Comment: What do you mean by `but i am having trouble making it work with a NSMutableArray`? What does work, what doesn't? Doesn't the tableView update?

Comment: @HAS yeah its not updating. if i set a breakpoint on `[tableview reloaddata]` i can see that dataArray has no objects in xcode

Comment: Most likely you're using a pointer somewhere that is nil, because you initialized a similarly-named pointer somewhere else, but not the **same** pointer.  But it would be most helpful (and keep this question from being quickly closed) if you actually described (ideally with error messages pasted in) what is going wrong.

Comment: @Wain on the navigation bar of secondviewcontroller i have a add button. when the button is pressed a modal is displayed with three textfields and a round rect button when the button is pressed it should update the tableview but it doesnt

Comment: @HotLicks but there are no error messages. i have thoroughly checked the code for almost 2 hours now.

Comment: Then what is not working right??  The first step in solving a problem is recognizing what it is.

Comment: @HotLicks The tableview is still blank

Comment: Where do you declare and how do init your `NSMutableArray` you use to populate the `tableView`?

Comment: @HAS I made a property in my header file for NSMutableArray synthesized it in my implementation. i then alloc and init ed in my viewdidload

Comment: You say that dataArray has no data.  This would account for the view being blank, I suspect.  Maybe you should inspect where you initialize that.  Add NSLog statements to trace every time you add some data.  **Do some actual debugging!!**

Comment: @HotLicks i did that. i did something like NSlog("dataArray: ", dataArray); it only showed the last object added

Comment: I'm guessing this is because you're doing what Wain said -- creating a new set of data structures every time you press that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your press the 'round rect' button, you're creating a new `second view controller`, passing it some data, asking it to do something and then throwing it away.

You need to update your `addArray:` method to call `addToArray:` on your **existing** `second view controller`.

You should probably do this by passing a reference to `second view controller` to the modal when you show it as a result of the bar button being pressed.

In SecondViewControllerModal.h :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) SecondViewController *owningSecondViewController;
```

In SecondViewController.m :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"..."]) {
        SecondViewControllerModal *modalViewController = (SecondViewControllerModal *)segue.destinationViewController;
        modalViewController.owningSecondViewController = self;
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
- (IBAction)addArray:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:subjectName.text, setLetter.text, setOrder.text , nil];

    [self.owningSecondViewController addToArray:content];
}
```

Comment: ahhh thaat makes sense, but how would i pass the current view? sorry objc noob here

Comment: i mean what exactly do i write?

Comment: i dont programmatically add the modal view controller i make it in interface builder

Comment: please add the code from your bar button method to the question.

Comment: actually, addtoarray in secondcontrollerview is the method called when the add button is pressed

Comment: ok, in your storyboard you drew a line between the 2 views (second and second modal). That defines a segue. You gave it a name. What was the name?